# Angular 5 view not updating on Firefox 57 Linux

Tags: angular, firefox

I am a beginner to Angular, and I have encountered a strange problem. Say I have a basic two way data binding example:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="title">
{{ title }}
```

Now, whenever I type into the textbox, my {{ title }} should change as well. However, that is not the case in Firefox 57 for Linux. This example works perfectly on Chromium or even Firefox for Android.

By the way, it's not only the two way data binding not working. Whenever I update a component property after the page has loaded (using an event) the view never changes on Firefox.

I have no idea what to do. I haven't really messed with any settings on my browser. Could this be a firefox bug? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: 
I reinstalled Fedora on my computer and it seems to work perfectly on the same Firefox version now. I still have no idea what the problem was.

Comment: have you any error in your console ?

Comment: Nope, no errors, just `Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It seems to work in other versions of Firefox, just not 57